# What type of file is the README file in sudoers.d?

Tags: sudo, files

Just  curious...figured would be a nice file to read with all my administrative privileges and not...LOL. Will not open since Ubuntu can't identify file type.

Don't worry, im not gonna change it, i promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple text-only file.  You can read it by running

```
sudo less /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

This file isn't really that important to the function of the system, so if you edit it it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

"Will not open"? How are you trying to open it? Here are some commands I used on my system:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ls -l /etc/sudoers.d
total 8
-r--r----- 1 root root 1626 Dec 28  2013 IPCop
-r--r----- 1 root root  958 Feb 10  2014 README
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ sudo file /etc/sudoers.d/README
[sudo] password for w3: 
/etc/sudoers.d/README: ASCII text
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/README
#
# As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default /etc/sudoers file created on
# installation of the package now includes the directive:
# 
#   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
# 
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d 
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
# 
# Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this
# one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.
# 
# Note also, that because sudoers contents can vary widely, no attempt is 
# made to add this directive to existing sudoers files on upgrade.  Feel free
# to add the above directive to the end of your /etc/sudoers file to enable 
# this functionality for existing installations if you wish!
#
# Finally, please note that using the visudo command is the recommended way
# to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes.
# See the man page for visudo for more information.
#
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ sudo mimetype /etc/sudoers.d/README
/etc/sudoers.d/README: text/x-readme
```

Comment: I had an answer, but yours is better.  Plus, I think I read the question wrong.  +1  :)

Comment: just learning the stuff on my own, i just tried clicking on it